# Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: smartcontracts

Following a tutorial online to learn about minting NFTs - https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-nfts-with-javascript/

I keep getting this error, and I've tried reviewing different posts but I still can't seem to bypass it.

```
(node:28474) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "transactionHash": "0x70b857fb9adf1539b7b8e9612c1c5e2a470b4db9bc4060b943bcd75b85ca36d9",
  "blockHash": "0x79f98597420377cf932ac053db4051c76c40347337413949c0e61044a3c490dc",
  "blockNumber": 11554713,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 22945,
  "effectiveGasPrice": "0x4a817c800",
  "from": "0x6031679a1230b03acb601bd5d643de4dfe93ac1c",
  "gasUsed": 22945,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xfcacbb204e0d93776cfd9a7f26f8333547e11dde",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "type": "0x0"
}
    at Object.TransactionError (/Users/x224631/Applications/LlamaClub/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:87:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (/Users/x224631/Applications/LlamaClub/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:98:21)
    at /Users/x224631/Applications/LlamaClub/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:393:57
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:28474) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 7)
(node:28474) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here's my smart contract file (.sol)

```
//Contract based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

// implements the ERC721 standard
// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
// keeps track of the number of tokens issued
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

// Accessing the Ownable method ensures that only the creator of the smart contract can interact with it
contract TorNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    mapping(string => uint8) hashes;

    // the name and symbol for the NFT
    constructor() public ERC721("LlamaClub", "TOR") {}

    // Create a function to mint/create the NFT
    // receiver takes a type of address. This is the wallet address of the user that should receive the NFT minted using the smart contract
    // tokenURI takes a string that contains metadata about the NFT

    function createNFT(
        address receiver,
        // string memory hash,
        string memory tokenURI
    ) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(receiver, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function of the contract was called and what data was transmitted to the contract?